# Pod для пейджинатора как в Instagram?

Tags: ios, swift, pagination

Подскажите pod для пейджинатора с тремя разными размерами точек, такой же как у Инстаграмма:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я просто загулил ваш запрос и сразу же нашел на него ответ:
https://github.com/shima11/FlexiblePageControl
На гитхаб есть и другие подобные поды.

Comment: спасибо ) да, я чет видать совсем плохо искал или не туда смотрел - извиняюсь )